# how do I modify docker-compose.yml to download mysql 5.6 for an apple m2 silicon running Ventura OSX 13?

Tags: mysql, docker, apple-m1, mysql-5.6

I have a docker-compose.yml file that looks like:

```
version: '3'
services:

  mysql:
    image: dtr.s-9.us/mysql:5.6
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'mydb'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'mypassword'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./mydb_dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 7080:8080
```

I'm am running an Apple Silicon M2 MacPro, and when I ran `docker-compose up` a month ago, everything worked perfectly (both the mysql 5.6 image and the adminer image downloaded successfully).

A month later (still Apple Silicon M2 MacPro), I re-run `docker-compose up` and I get the following error:

```
docker-compose up
[+] Running 4/1
 ✔ Network mydb_default                                                                                                                              Created                                                                           0.1s 
 ✔ Container mydb-mysql-1                                                                                                                            Created                                                                           0.0s 
 ✔ Container mydb-adminer-1                                                                                                                          Created                                                                           0.0s 
 ! mysql The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested                                                                                   0.0s 
Attaching to mydb-adminer-1, mydb-mysql-1
mydb-mysql-1    | exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
mydb-adminer-1  | [Thu Jun  8 23:38:55 2023] PHP 7.4.33 Development Server (http://[::]:8080) started
mydb-mysql-1 exited with code 0
mydb-mysql-1 exited with code 1
mydb-mysql-1 exited with code 1
mydb-mysql-1 exited with code 1
```

My hunch is there is a problem with this line in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
   image: dtr.s-9.us/mysql:5.6    <-- perhaps https://dtr.s-9us registry is down?
```

When I try to hit `https://dtr.s-9us` in my web browser it appears to be down.  Could this be the problem? If so, is there another docker registry that has mysql 5.6 for Apple M2 silicon?

FYI: If the change the above line to:

```
image: mysql:8
```

it succesfully downloads MySQL 8.0 for Apple M2 Silicon, which is nice, but that's not the version I need ( I need the same MySQL 5.6 docker image for Apple M2 I downloaded a month ago).

Comment: 5.6 is long past end of life and is insecure (in addition to apparently being difficult to find); upgrade to 8 or mariadb 10.6 or 10.11 as soon as you can

Comment: If it's down, it's down. Unless you have it locally cached you're stuck. What is that container repository anyway?

Comment: I know that I can have somebody send me the mysql 5.6 image by using docker save <image> command: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/ .  But this just seems very silly.  I feel like docker is better than this, and there must be a way for me to get the image I'm looking for the right way.